# Site redirecionando para url com / no final

Tags: php, htaccess

Quando entro no meu site
www.exemplo.com

Ele redireciona para
www.exemplo.com/

Como resolver isso?

Segue o meu .haccess

```
Options -Indexes
```

```
#Ativamos a RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?idealnutri\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.idealnutri.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ gera_xml.php [L] 
RewriteRule ^noticia/([^/]*)\.html$ /noticia.php?link=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score -1):

Tenho a impressão que o problema está no momento em que você força o HTTPS

Tenta assim:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.+) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
RewriteRule ^ https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```